# Working with multiple git branches of Neovim config

Tags: neovim, git, neovim-qt

I am working with multiple NVim configs through multiple git branches but it appears to be broken like it doesn't update the config after I switch branch and restart Neovim. Restarting my computer does make the change happens. Only sometimes and erratically. In fact I can't be sure it is actually the trigger. Why is that? How can I fix it?

I am talking about the ~\AppData\local\nvim config (I am on Windows).

Comment: Could you tell us what is the exact symptom and what is exactly covered by the Neovim config? Is it ~/AppData/local/nvim` is it more (nvim-data?)?

Answer (score 0):

I think running PackerSync solves the issue.

Comment: That assumes they're using packer.nvim